# Random spawn location in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Here is a function that I made, it spawns an object at a fixed location, but I want it to spawn randomly inside the phone screen (which is 1080x1920).

```
-- BALLOON SPAWN FUNCTION
function spawnBalloon( event )
    balloon = display.newImage("balloon1.png")
    balloon.x = display.contentCenterX 
    balloon.y = display.contentCenterY
    balloon:addEventListener("tap", spawnBalloon)
    balloon:addEventListener("tap", removeBalloon)
end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
local _T = display.screenOriginY
local _B = display.viewableContentHeight - display.screenOriginY
local _L = display.screenOriginX
local _R = display.viewableContentWidth - display.screenOriginX
local mRandom = math.random
...
balloon.x = mRandom( _L, _R )
balloon.y = mRandom( _T, _B )
```

Center of object remains on the screen.